# In DB Browser for SQLite, How DO I Save An Edited FIle Without Changing Its Format?

Tags: sqlite, editing

I opened a file whose header says SQLite 3 and edited the value of 2 fields. I didn't change its structure. I tried saving, exporting etc but I never get a file with the same header as the original - and the program that uses this file says it is in the wrong format (or absent).

I tried the .dump command and got a file which begins: PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF; BEGIN TRANSACTION; CREATE TABLE locales ( locale_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, locale_uuid TEXT UNIQUE, locale_code TEXT

What I need is a file with the same format as the file I began my DB Browser for SQLite session by editing, which has these opening lines: SQLite 3
[the remaining characters result in an error message if I try pasting them in here) I see many characters did not paste well here! But you get the idea - the file I am able to save/export/dump out of the app is in plain text and the file I am trying to edit ONE PIECE OF DATA IN is not.

Perhaps I should have told you upfront these are my first 20 minutes in the world of editing SQL! (Mac 10.14.6)I will try to attach the file I started with.

Tried all the commands in the File menu - save, export. Tried terminal .dump

Comment: How did you open to edit the file?

Comment: Are you using a text editor to modify a sqlite database file, which follows a strict, well defined *binary* format? That's a good way to corrupt the file so sqlite can't load it.

Comment: I am using "DB Browser for SQLite" for Mac. I open with the File Open command.

Answer (score 0):

Just write an Update data routine. Here is code for a C# app
It checks that the data is valid then when you click the update button
presto magic data is updated

```
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!validateInput())
        {
            return;
        }
        if (!validateEmail())
        {
            return;
        }
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "UPDATE FriendsData SET fxFirstName = @fxFirstName, fxLastName = @fxLastName,fxAddress = @fxAddress,fxCity = @fxCity, fxState = @fxState,fxZip = @fxZip,fxCellPhone = @fxCellPhone,fxEmail = @fxEmail,fxInfo = @fxInfo WHERE FID =" + userData.udID;
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxFirstName",tbFirstName.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxLastName",tbLastName.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxAddress",tbAddress.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxCity",tbCity.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxState",tbState.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxZip",tbZip.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxCellPhone",mtbCellPhone.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxEmail",tbEmail.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxInfo",rtbInfo.Rtf.Trim());

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.ToString();
                    tbMessage.Text = result;
                }
            }
        }
        tbMessage.Text = "Information Updated";
        btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
        btnClose.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand - I am using DB Browser for SQLite for Mac. Where in this app do I write the code you have supplied?

Comment: @HughP When you ask a question you need to tag your question with the OS you are using My answer is Windows Code To Update a database record you first load the record you want to change then you issue a SQLite Update command LOOK AT THE string sql in the provided code and put this code behind a button click event

Comment: Since this is my first post perhaps you can explain how I can edit this post to have the tags needed.  I mentioned I was usingDB Browser for SqLite on a Macintosh/. Your response says it is for Windows, and to change a record! I CAN change the record. I do not think my post was understood.

Comment: @HughP To edit your post click on edit At this point in the process of answering your question show us some code that you have written to Edit a record in SQLite Other question do you know how to click a button to execute some code?

Comment: I am not writing code. I am changing a value in a filed. When I save the file it is in a different format than when I loaded it. It is no longer read by the program that read the file perfectly before I edited that field. The program that reads the database is not relevnt, but FYI it is Finale, a music notation program.